# TDD: How to test result when a method my return different result depending on the input?

Tags: c#, tdd

Let's say, I have this class

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int MyMethod(int? i)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

I have also a test class

```
[TestClass]
public class MyClassTest
{
  Public void Retur_Int_Greater_Than_Zero_When_Input_Is_Not_Null_And_Zero_Otherwise()
  {
     // Arrange
     var myVar = new MyClass();
     int? i = 3;

    // Act
    var result = myVar.MyMethod(i)  

   //Assert
   //
  } 
}
```

I'd like to check - if the input is null or 0, the result must be 0 - if the input is not null nor 0, the result must the absolute value of that number.

**How do I express those assertions?**

Can I write something like:

```
if(i.HasValue)
{
  //Define the Assert statement inside a If, else constructions...
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Express them exactly how you've described them: create 2 test methods. First passes null or 0 and checks that result is 0 in both cases, and second passes some negative and positive values and checks that absolute value is returned.

Comment: @zerkms: Can u please do it???

Comment: Uhm, it is pretty trivial. I think you need to read basics about testing framework you use (or not test your code at all, as long as you just cannot do that)

Comment: @zerkms: I've just started learning how to test code. So, this is one of the first challenge.

Comment: `can u please do it` is a weird way to learn then. Read articles and documentation, *get the idea* of why and how tests are written, not just follow the snippets found on internet and got here.

Comment: @zerkms: Man, u are not being helpfull. Do you think I need to read how many books before start practicing? Thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: as you pointed before - you're trying to learn, so I tried to teach. But actually you don't want that, you just want ready to copy-and-paste solution. That's sad. Good luck in your "learning" anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create three tests instead of one to test three different scenarios

**If the input is null or 0, the result must be 0**

```
// Act
var result = myVar.MyMethod(null)  
//Assert
Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(0));

// Act
var result = myVar.MyMethod(0)  
//Assert
Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(0));
```

**If the input is not null nor 0, the result must the absolute value of that number.**

```
// Act
int graterThatZero = 1;
int absoluteValue = //define it here;
var result = myVar.MyMethod(graterThatZero)  
//Assert
Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(absoluteValue));
```

**The same using TestCase attribute from NUnit**

```
[TestCase(null,0)]
[TestCase(0,0)]
[TestCase(1, 1 /* absolute value */)]
[TestCase(-1, 1)]
public void MyMethod_should_return_absolute_value(int? argument, int expectedResult)
{
   // Arrange
   var myVar = new MyClass();
   // Act
   var result = myVar.MyMethod(argument) 
   // Assert
   Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expectedResult));
}
```

Comment: I'd also add negative value case.

Comment: @Restuta: Using VS2010 Unit Test, I don't get Assert.That(); Which framework are u using?

Comment: NUnit, MSTest that you are using inside VS2010 do not have such a piece of cake, so you should go with four separate tests instead.

Comment: And also MSTest has not "Assert.That" but "Assert.Equals(result, expectedResult);"

Answer (score 1):

Don't use if-else contructs in tests. If you are using Nunit have a look at [Parameterized tests](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=parameterizedTests&r=2.5) - you can use the `TestCaseAttribute` to specify your input and output. Or, create separate tests for the different inputs.

Another principle that you can follow while writing unit tests ( and doing TDD) is that the test name should not have an `and` in it. That means you are testing two things. From the test name that you are trying to give, you can see that you need to split up the tests.

Sample test:

```
[TestCase(null,0)]
[TestCase(0,0)]
[TestCase(10,10)]
[TestCase(-10,10)]
public void TestItWorksForInput(int? input, int expectedOutput)
{
   var myVar = new MyClass();
   var output = myVar.MyMethod(argument);
   Assert.That(output, Is.EqualTo(expectedOutput));
}
```

Also note that you have to test the boundary conditions and makes sure you have test for each of them. In the above, though there is just only one test written, when it runs, it runs as 4 and you can even see if and when one or more of them fail.

Again, the test sample is for Nunit. If you are using MSTest, Xunit, Mbunit, etc. the syntax and assertions will differ, but the principles remain the same.

Comment: @zerkms - Why not an answer? Answers are not only those that have code

Comment: indeed, but in this exact case OP just **doesn't know** how to write tests :-) So parameterized, or not - this knowledge pointless as long as he doesn't know how to write assertions. +1 anyway

Comment: @zerkms - Actually, you are right. I did not notice that. Thanks. I have added sample test.